# What would you recommend to know before considering applying for a master in Machine Learning?

Tags: self-study

As someone who is about to finish a bachelor in Software Engineering still learning the basics of machine learning but would like to enroll in a master's course focused on machine learning.

What would you recommend to learn before considering applying for a master?

I'd like to hear experiences of people who have gone through ML or computer science with a focus on ML or have taught at that level, what is the expected knowledge you are suppose to have?

Comment: Calculus, probability, and statistics. Make sure your MS syllabus includes courses in linear algebra and optimization. And by the time you graduate you should be able to at least understand any ML paper with a little effort.